# Edit a Mathematica plot in Illustrator, missing font problem

Tags: export, fonts, eps-format

I export my *Mathematica* generated plot as an eps file and then I open it in Adobe Illustrator to make a few changes. When I try to do this I get this error message:

> Times-Roman:
>       Font not found on the system; missing font has been substituted.

But the substituted font looks terrible.

How can I make Illustrator load the correct fonts on a Windows 7 box?

Comment: Could you provide a small `Plot` example that exhibits this behavior? Please also include the specific `Export` command you use.

Comment: I did it in the past with Illustrator. At that time I exported the graphics without any text. It was for the same reason. I added then the text by hands already within the Illustrator, along with some minor additional graphics, such as some lines arrows etc. Now I prefer to finalize everything in Mma.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't run Windows, but I do know how to fix this problem on Mac OS X ([see my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#OfficialFontSolution)).

Based on that, I can at least provide a guess as to what you should do. However, I **can't guarantee** that it will work because I have no way to try it. So use this prescription at your own risk:

- Download the Mathematica fronts [from the official web site](http://support.wolfram.com/technotes/fonts/windows/latestfonts.html) (they also come with MMA, but I don't know where they reside on Windows).
- In the extracted directory, locate the `Type1` folder
- In another window, find the directory `<System Disk>:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts` (the `Adobe` folder should already exist, but you may have to create the `Fonts` folder.
- Drag the `Type1` folder found in the first step into the directory found in the last step.

Now restart Illustrator, and with some luck you'll have the Math fonts available.

Comment: The `Type1` folder does not contain the `Times-Roman` font mentioned in the question.

Comment: The same error message, but the substituted font is a lot nicer! thanks

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work the way I hoped. Maybe someone else will find a better answer -

Comment: Thank you! It worked! If there's still a missing font we can now just copy it to that folder.

Comment: Oh man ... thank you SO much. I was about to have a class one hissy fit about how crappy Mathematica export is... You are a life saver.

Comment: Just a heads up: In Win8, this worked by exporting all the fonts in the Type1 folder into `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC (64 Bit)\Support Files\Required\Fonts`. I could not find the path that @jens provided in the answer

Comment: Do you have any hints [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89022/12)?

Comment: Would you kindly update your answer for Mathematica 10?  Copying the fonts to the `Adobe\Fonts` directory doesn't seem to work anymore.  (Mac OSX)

Comment: @QuantumDot I stopped using Illustrator when they fully switched to a subscription model, so I can't test any fixes now. But outlining fonts before importing into Illustrator has always been the most fool-proof solution. On Macs, I also have my own solution independent of *Mathematica*: [fontBegone](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/FontBegone/).

Comment: @Jens The fontBegone works beautifully! Thanks for sharing! It also compresses the file size of pdf figure greatly.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate the solution given by Jens and find it's a nice one. The problem with that solution is that the required font Times-Roman is actually missing from the Type1 Mathematica folder. So I just wanted to share  a workaround I found. It's very simple.

1. Open your pdf in Adobe Illustrator, hit OK when proposed to use a substitute font.
2. Go to the **Type->Find Font** menu in Adobe Illustrator.
3. Choose the missing *Times* font in the top part of the window.
4. **Replace with**, choose **System**
5. In the big list choose *Times New Roman* or similar.
6. Hit **Change all**.

The result I get is practically indistinguishable from the original pdf, and all the text is on its place, that means no onverlaps which may happen if using the default substitute font.

Hope it helps.