# Front end crash on Export in 10.2 on OS X

Tags: bugs, mac-os-x, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 and fixed in 10.3.0** 

 Appears to be specific to OS X

---

*Mathematica* 10.2 is reliably crashing for me when trying to export a pdf that has text with ligatures. For example:

```
ExportString[Text["fi"], "PDF"]
```

crashes the front end.

Is anyone else seeing this? I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.4.

Comment: Yes, I have 10.2 on OS X 10.10.5.  It also crashed for me today when I used [Alexey's code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89088/12) to try to export a sample of every font I have installed.  It might be related.  I didn't track down which font it was but some have ligatures for lots of character combinations.  Or maybe a font name just had "fi" in it.

Comment: Can you report it to support and link back here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Windows or Linux, only on OS X.

Comment: This crash is due to a bug in the [Pango](http://www.pango.org) library. It has already been fixed upstream and in the development version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: I can confirm the crash on OS X and 10.2 Mathematica.

Comment: @ilian **No crash** for me with v10.2.0 and **OSX 10.9.5**. Even `Export["test.pdf", Text["fi"]]` creates a pdf file displaying the correct ligature. I checked the dependencies of the Mathematica executable, and (concerning Pango) it is linked to libpango-1.0.0.dylib and libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib, both with the mention *(compatibility version 3601.0.0, current version 3601.0.0)*.

Comment: yes, mma 10.2 on OS X 10.10.5 crashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading my comment into an answer, now that *Mathematica* 10.3 has been [released](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/583220).

> This crash was due to a bug in the [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) library. It has already been fixed upstream and in *Mathematica* 10.3.

```
$Version

(* "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

Show[ImportString[ExportString[Text["fi"], "PDF"], "PDF"], ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]